# Can I use a SELECT query output tu set the value of a field directly into an INSERT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, rdbms

I am not so into DB and I have the following doubt working on a MySql insert query.

I have to insert a new record in a table using the insert statment, something like this (returning always a single record):

```
INSERT INTO MeteoForecast VALUES(
                                    localization_id,
                                    start_date,
                                  ) 
VALUES(
)
```

The problem is that the value related to the **localization_id** field is retrieved from another query, this one:

```
SELECT LCZ.id                                       AS localization_id
FROM Localization                                   AS LCZ                           
INNER JOIN Region                                   AS RGN
      ON LCZ.region_id = RGN.id
INNER JOIN District                                AS DST
      ON LCZ.district_id = DST.id
WHERE
      RGN.region_name = "Kigali City"  
AND
      DST.district_name = "Kigali"
```

So my doubt is: can I use this query output to set the value of my **localization_id** parameter? Or is it impossible? In case it is possible could be a good idea or isn't?

Comment: Does this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) help?

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is possible. Change the #start_date# with the value you have. If the "select from localization" returns one row, one row will be inserted into MeteoForecast.

```
INSERT INTO MeteoForecast VALUES(
                                    localization_id,
                                    start_date,
                                  ) 
(
SELECT LCZ.id , #start_date#
FROM Localization                                   AS LCZ                           
INNER JOIN Region                                   AS RGN
      ON LCZ.region_id = RGN.id
INNER JOIN District                                AS DST
      ON LCZ.district_id = DST.id
WHERE
      RGN.region_name = "Kigali City"  
AND
      DST.district_name = "Kigali"
)
```